# Submission with spark-submit to the master using yarn results in the worker trying to resolve the hostname (docker container) of the caller

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-submit

Seems submitting with spark-submit results in the worker node trying to call back the host that called spark-submit.

Note the hostname of the docker container

sara@e4f76e66ba41:~$ spark-submit --master yarn foo.py
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.5.0
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO SparkContext: OS info Linux, 5.10.0-25-cloud-amd64, amd64
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO SparkContext: Java version 17.0.8.1
23/10/11 20:41:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: foo.py
23/10/11 20:41:00 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name:
.........
.........
.........
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sara/foo.py", line 8, in 
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
^^^23/10/11 20:41:20 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 497, in getOrCreate
23/10/11 20:41:20 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 515, in getOrCreate
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 203, in **init**
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 296, in _do_init
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 421, in _initialize_context
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1587, in **call**
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value

In the worker logs

```
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to e4f76e66ba41:41395
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: e4f76e66ba41
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
```

specifically

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: e4f76e66ba41

Why is this happening? is this intended? is it intended that the worker nodes need to reach the caller itself? I can definitely set up routes and DNS but this is very strange coming from an app development background.

Comment: Is it a Dataproc issue? It doesn't seem to be because I saw "Spark version 3.5.0" in the log.